# maven: war:war rebuilds war even when content unchanged - why?

Tags: maven, war

why does maven ear plugin runs the war:war (plugin goal) when I try to build the ear project from netbeans

my process:

I right click on the ear project (which has the war dependency listed) and first Clean and then right click on it and select Build with Dependencies. Then it builds the war again using the war:war and it takes time. even though there was no change in the war but will re create it again.

this is what it says :

> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ Building finweb 1.0-SNAPSHOT
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ The POM for org.netbeans.external:jdom-1.0:jar:RELEASE71 is missing,
>   no dependency information available The POM for
>   com.ibm:com.ibm.mq:jar:6.0.2.5 is missing, no dependency information
>   available The POM for com.ibm:com.ibm.mqbind:jar:6.0.2.5 is missing,
>   no dependency information available The POM for
>   net.sf.saxon:saxon:jar:10.0-b19 is missing, no dependency information
>   available
>
> [dependency:copy]
>
> [resources:resources] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered
>   resources. skip non existing resourceDirectory
>   C:\Beta\fin\finweb\src\main\resources
>
> [compiler:compile] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
>
> [resources:testResources] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered
>   resources. skip non existing resourceDirectory
>   C:\Beta\fin\finweb\src\test\resources
>
> [compiler:testCompile] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
>
> [surefire:test] No tests to run. Surefire report directory:
>   C:\Beta\fin\finweb\target\surefire-reports
>
> -------------------------------------------------------  T E S T S
>   ------------------------------------------------------- There are no tests to run.
>
> Results :
>
> Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
>
> [war:war] Packaging webapp Assembling webapp [finweb] in
>   [C:\Beta\fin\finweb\target\finweb-1.0-SNAPSHOT] Processing war
>   project Copying webapp resources
>   [C:\Beta\fin\finweb\src\main\webapp] Webapp assembled in [109467
>   msecs] Building war:
>   C:\Beta\fin\finweb\target\finweb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war WEB-INF\web.xml
>   already added, skipping
>
> [install:install] Installing
>   C:\Beta\fin\finweb\target\finweb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war to C:\Documents
>   and
>   Settings.m2\repository\com\comp\finweb\1.0-SNAPSHOT\finweb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
>   Installing C:\Beta\fin\finweb\pom.xml to C:\Documents and
>   Settings\5510041.m2\repository\com\comp\finweb\1.0-SNAPSHOT\finweb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom

So if there is nothing to compile why would it build a war again if it was already made and there are no changes. is this the default behaviour, looking at compile : compile when it doesnt compile if there is nothing needed then why does war:war does it, it shud be intelligent enuff to do it right?

pls correct me if I am wrong

Thanks in advance..

Syed.

Answer (score 3):

This may be considered as workaround.
Following configs will speed up your build time.

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
 <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>2.4</version>
 <configuration>
  <useCache>true</useCache>
  <recompressZippedFiles>false</recompressZippedFiles>
 </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Reference :https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html

Also am looking forward for easy way to skip war:war phase from maven default build lifecycle.

Answer (score 1):

Your concern can be understood. But in principle maven-war-plugin does not know that the resulting WAR artifact will be identical to one which was build a minute ago because:

- You might define `MANIFEST` entry that contains the current build time.
- You might enable different profile, which will change the picture completely.
- Other plugins (like maven-ant-plugin, maven-dependency-plugin) might add something to target directory depending on some changing conditions (e.g. property from command line).

So it is safer to rebuild war each time. On modern platforms this is really negligible.

Comment: "On modern platforms this is really negligible" - his output says "Webapp assembled in [109467 msecs]" which is approaching two minutes.

Comment: I agree, there might be areas for improvement, but in general case the optimization problem is hardly solvable and may results other side effects. You may think about other ways to speedup your build, for example create in-memory fs (`tmpfs`) and build your project there. Memory chips are cheap :)

Comment: for what mvn clean is for then ?

Comment: You mean that `mvn clean` should somehow speedup the build? I doubt :)